# using jQuery to slide one div down and the other visible divs up (sliding content based navigation)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Figured I would ask here because I can't seem to find an easy solution  or a solution on here that fits my needs.  The problem I'm having with my site at the moment is when dealing with slide animations and with timing of those animations.

So when a user clicks one of my navigation buttons there is a panel that slides out the content based on the button pressed.  if you click another button it will slide that one previous div back up and slide down the new content panel.

The main problem I'm getting is either I get animation timing issues because the other one starts sliding as the other one is for some reason.

All my content panels are siblings to one another...so here's the jQuery I'm using....any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
$('a.navBtn').click(function(){
    var divName = this.name;
    $.when(function(){
        $("#"+divName).siblings().filter(":visible").slideUp("slow");
    }).then(function(){
        $("#"+divName).slideDown("slow");
    })
});

<div id="services">
                    <div class="noise_overlay">
                        <div id="contact"><a href="#" class="navBtn" name="contactContent"><img src="i/contact.png" /></a></div>
                        <div id="linkedin"><a href="#" class="navBtn" name="linkedinContent"><img src="i/linkedin.png" /></a></div>
                        <div id="facebook"><a href="#" class="navBtn" name="facebookContent"><img src="i/facebook.png" /></a></div>
                        <div id="twitter"><a href="#" class="navBtn" name="twitterContent"><img src="i/twitter.png" /></a></div>
                        <div id="flickr"><a href="#" class="navBtn" name="flickrContent"><img src="i/flickr.png" /></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<div id="serviceContent">
            <div id="contactContent" class="contentPane mpHidden">
                <div class="noise_overlay_300">
                    <div id="contactData">
                        <span>contact</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentFooter"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="linkedinContent" class="contentPane mpHidden">
                <div class="noise_overlay_300">
                    <div id="linkedinData" class="mpCenter">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentFooter"><span></span></div>
            </div>
            <div id="facebookContent" class="contentPane mpHidden">
                <div class="noise_overlay_300">
                    <div id="facebookData" class="mpCenter">
                        <span>facebook</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentFooter"><span></span></div>
            </div>
            <div id="twitterContent" class="contentPane mpHidden">
                <div class="noise_overlay_300">
                    <div id="twitterData" class="mpCenter">
                        <span>twitter</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentFooter"><span></span></div>
            </div>
            <div id="flickrContent" class="contentPane mpHidden">
                <div class="noise_overlay_300">
                    <div id="flickrData" class="mpCenter">
                        <span>flickr</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contentFooter"><span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you please also post your HTML?

Comment: @Andrew Peacock i edited the main post with the html. thanks.

Comment: There are no 'a.navBtn' in your HTML snippet. Could you please add the exact markup so that ppl could reproduce the issue?

Comment: @spliter i added my navigation snippet above the content divs.  thanks again

Comment: @spliter do you need the CSS and everything as well? I just don't want to flood that panel with all the CSS3 I use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain your animation events so the slideDown doesn't happen until the slideUp is done:

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

```
 $("#"+divName).siblings().filter(":visible").slideUp("slow", function() {
     $("#"+divName).slideDown("slow");
 });
```

Should be something like that.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work....i'm guessing because something has to be visible first?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working(?) version. I use the callback of the `slideUP` to call the `slideDown`.

http://jsfiddle.net/yazYF/

**EDIT**: Just like the Justin said, I just have some code to test with. :)

**EDIT 2**: Now with an initial pane visible

http://jsfiddle.net/yazYF/1/

**EDIT 3**: Initially nothing...

http://jsfiddle.net/yazYF/2/

Comment: This worked great!  What if I want no panes visible in the beginning?  If I don't have one visible in the beginning then it doesn't seem to work.  Otherwise it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple [jQuery snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/cQdTq/) for you. The javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.navBtn').click(function(e) {
        var pane = $(this).attr('name'),
            switchPanes = function(name) {
                if($('.contentPane:visible').attr('id') === name){
                    return;
                }
                if($('.contentPane:visible').length > 0){
                    $('.contentPane:visible').slideUp('fast', function() {
                        $('#' + name).slideDown('medium');
                    });                    
                } else {
                    $('#' + name).slideDown('medium');                    
                }
            };

        switchPanes(pane);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```